# Is it possible to create a database on fly in PostgreSQL for Azure using Java code if it does not exist? If yes, how?

Tags: java, postgresql, azure, azure-sql-database

I want to create database and tables on the fly in PostgreSQL in Azure cloud **using Java code**.
How to create a database in PostgreSQL for Azure using Java code if it does not exist?

Comment: Assuming that you want to create a Postgres VM, you can access Azure API, you can do that via API. https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-pt/azure/virtual-machines/linux/create-vm-rest-api

Comment: In theory you can run `create database ...` through Java/JDBC - but you need to have a privileged user in order to be able to do that. Whether that is possible on Azure I don't know. It's not "vanilla" Postgres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect to the server through an Admin User

And run the following query:

```sql
CREATE DATABASE database_name OWNER your_owner;
```

For more information check [this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/sql-createdatabase.html).

This is plain Java though, you have to check whether something like this is possible in Azure.